# Laravel Form escapes text to entities

Tags: laravel, html-entities

When populating a selectbox `{{Form::select(blah,blah)}}` in laravel if it contains unicode characters they are converted to `&mu;&alpha;&lambda;&#940;&kappa;&alpha;&sigmaf;`  . This increases page size. I couldnt find any fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

> in laravel if it contains unicode characters they are converted to &mu &alpha &lambda &#940  &kappa &alpha &sigmaf

Yes - that is intentional to help prevent XSS and other related issues.

> This increases page size

The amount of 'page' size increases is negligible. It does not matter. There are about 1,000 other things you should focus on to improve efficiency before this would ever be a problem.

Your best way to reduce page size with Laravel is to minify your HTML before output - with packages like this one: https://github.com/fitztrev/laravel-html-minify